# Check a column value to populate multiple columns in hive

Tags: sql, hiveql

I am trying to create a table Y. I am stuck in the following condition: -

If column a of table X is 1 (X.a = 'Y') then X.b will populate Y.b and X.c will populate Y.c.

If column a of table X is 0 (X.a = 'N') then X.b will populate Y.d and X.c will populate Y.e

I have tried using "case when" but that gives me 2 rows. I need to keep just 1 row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvSz7.png)

### TABLE X

### a   |    b     |    c    |

### Y   |    1     |    3    |

### N   |    2     |    4    |

### TABLE Y

### b   |    c     |    d    |   e   |

### 1   |    3     |    2    |   4   |

I need the result like this.

How do I implement this condition in HiveQl?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I added some sample values and result.

Comment: @leftjoin I renamed it. The source table is X. The target table is Y that is being created

Comment: a is in (Y,N) in your table, but you say this: "If column a of table X is 1 (X.a = 1)" How can it be?

Comment: Y is supposed to mean 1 and N is supposed to mean 0. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
create table y as
   select (case when x.a = 1 then x.b end) as b,
          (case when x.a = 1 then x.c end) as c,
          (case when x.a = 0 then x.b end) as d,
          (case when x.a = 0 then x.c end) as e

   from x;
```

Comment: This gives me 2 rows in the target table. 1 row for X.a =1 and another for X.a=0. I need to keep the results in 1 row only

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` expressions + sum() aggregate:

```
insert overwrite table Y
select 
sum(case when x.a=1 then x.b end) as b
sum(case when x.a=1 then x.c end) as c
sum(case when x.a=0 then x.b end) as d
sum(case when x.a=0 then x.c end) as e
from
tableX x;
```

Comment: This gives me 2 rows in the target table. 1 row for X.a =1 and another for X.a=0. I need to keep the results in 1 row only

Comment: @Seeker90 Add aggregation then. See updated answer please

Comment: @Seeker90 for example, case expression for column b for a=0 will generate null and sum() will sum only not null. For a=1 it will be 1, sum =1. Also max() or min() will work the same as sum in this case